# python retrive and modify mp4 file properties in windows

Tags: python, file, video, properties

on my windows 10 system, I have organized a directory where I have stored hundreds of video files in mp4, avi and mkv formats. Using property interface of the file explorer I can read some of the properties  (like length) and read/modify others like title, subtitle, tags ….
Now I will like to read and modify this properties by mean of a Python program. I found out that I can use the python module os.path.size to read the size attribute but I do not find any module/functions to read/modify properties like title, subtitle, tags etc. Please suggest what module/function to use and how. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the MoviePy library for most of these things. For example, reading the video length can be done with the following:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

clip = VideoFileClip("video.mp4")
print(clip.duration)
```

If MoviePy doesn't have something you need, you can use FFmpeg which harder to use but has more capabilities. I think there is a python wrapper for FFmpeg, but when I've played around with it in the past I just used Popen and check_output from the subprocess library to call the commands.